# Convert query string to date object

Tags: express, query-string, feathersjs

I have a `GET` endpoint
`/internal/users?role=057426a1235fa1084c6f&lastLoggedIn[$lte]=2018-11-07T22:57:44.612Z`

I am using [featherjs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/) and [feathers-rest client](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/rest.html) to call my services.

My problem is I get the req.query as 

`{ role: '057426a1235fa1084c6f',
  lastLogged: { $lte: '2018-11-07T22:57:44.612Z' } }`

and I am getting date as string not date object.

is there any way I can transform my query to have the correct date object if I encountered any ISODate string?

I have tried something like

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const queryFlat = flat(req.query);
  for (key in queryFlat) {
    queryFlat[key] = dateCheck(queryFlat[key]) // dateCheck returns date object if ISODate String
  }
  req.query = unlfat(queryFlat)
});
```

This is working fine, but is there any way I can pass to `qs.parser` which can automatically convert date string to date Object?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `flat` and `unflat` can have problem if you pass some query with keys containing `.` itself.

so, this can help,
using [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) library

```
app.use(req, res, next) => {
   req.query = qs.parse(qs.stringify(req.query), {
    decoder: dateCheck, // dateCheck returns date object if ISODate String
  });
}
```

Your dateCheck function should be something like this

```
const dateCheck = (value, decoder) => {
  const key = decoder(value); // this 
  //      ... rest of date check function
}
```